# Entity Framework c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

This is my class `Igra`, it has the basic attributes.

```
public class Igra
{
    public  int IgraId { get; set; }
    public  string imeIgre { get; set; }

    public  string zvrstIgre { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Prodajalna> Prodajalna { get; set; }
}
```

This is my class `Prodajalna`, it also has the basic attributes.

```
public class Prodajalna
{
    public int ProdajalnaId { get; set; }
    public string imeProdajalne { get; set; }

    public  string naslovProdajalne { get; set; }

    public int IgraId;
    public virtual Igra igra{get;set;
}
```

They are both setup via ASMX service. Now when I do this in my Entity Framework context:

```
Igra i1 = new Igra() { imeIgre = "WoW", zvrstIgre = "MMORPG", 
                       Prodajalna = new List<Prodajalna>()
                     };
Igra i2 = new Igra() { imeIgre = "LoL", zvrstIgre = "MOBA", 
                       Prodajalna = new List<Prodajalna>() };
Igra i3 = new Igra() { imeIgre = "Diablo", zvrstIgre = "heh", 
                       Prodajalna = new List<Prodajalna>() };

i1.Prodajalna.Add(new Prodajalna() { imeProdajalne = "Bolha",
                                     naslovProdajalne = "Maribor" });
i1.Prodajalna.Add(new Prodajalna() { imeProdajalne = "Nekaj", 
                                     naslovProdajalne = "Ljubljana" });

i2.Prodajalna.Add(new Prodajalna() { imeProdajalne = "Nekaj2", 
                                     naslovProdajalne = "Koper" });

i3.Prodajalna.Add(new Prodajalna() { imeProdajalne = "Nekaj2", 
                                     naslovProdajalne = "Maribor" });
i3.Prodajalna.Add(new Prodajalna() { imeProdajalne = "Nekaj", 
                                     naslovProdajalne = "Ljubljana" });
i3.Prodajalna.Add(new Prodajalna() { imeProdajalne = "Nekaj2", 
                                     naslovProdajalne = "Koper" });
```

So here I just added some games and stores, no big deal. Now after I run this function:

```
List<Prodajalna> vse_prodajalne = gameshop.izpisi_vse_prodajalne();

foreach (Prodajalna p in vse_prodajalne)
    Console.WriteLine(p.imeProdajalne);
```

It's going to write out all the shops, so the program will write:

```
Bolha
Nekaj
Nekaj2
Nekaj
Nekaj2
```

The problem is that it should only write out:

```
Bolha
Nekaj
Nekaj2
```

so it's redundant in my database.

*UPDATE 1/1*
I have updated my code but it still doesn't work

```
 public class ProdajalnaVsebujeIgroContext : DbContext
    {  
        public DbSet<Igra> Igre { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Prodajalna> Prodajalne { get; set; }

        public ProdajalnaVsebujeIgroContext()//help
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<ProdajalnaVsebujeIgroContext>(new PVIInit());
            this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        }


        public class PVIInit : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ProdajalnaVsebujeIgroContext>
        {
            protected override void Seed(ProdajalnaVsebujeIgroContext context)
            {

                var p = new Prodajalna() { imeProdajalne = "Nekaj2", naslovProdajalne = "Koper" };
                ProdajalnaVsebujeIgroContext.
                context.SaveChanges();
                context.Prodajalne.Add(p);


                Igra i1 = new Igra() { imeIgre = "WoW", zvrstIgre = "MMORPG", Prodajalna = new List<Prodajalna>() };
                Igra i2 = new Igra() { imeIgre = "LoL", zvrstIgre = "MOBA", Prodajalna = new List<Prodajalna>() };
                Igra i3 = new Igra() { imeIgre = "Diablo", zvrstIgre = "heh", Prodajalna = new List<Prodajalna>() };

                i1.Prodajalna.Add(new Prodajalna() { imeProdajalne = "Bolha", naslovProdajalne = "Maribor" });
                i1.Prodajalna.Add(new Prodajalna() { imeProdajalne = p.imeProdajalne, naslovProdajalne = "Ljubljana" });

                i2.Prodajalna.Add(new Prodajalna() { imeProdajalne = p.imeProdajalne, naslovProdajalne = "Koper" });

                i3.Prodajalna.Add(new Prodajalna() { imeProdajalne = p.imeProdajalne, naslovProdajalne = "Maribor" });
                i3.Prodajalna.Add(new Prodajalna() { imeProdajalne = "Nekaj", naslovProdajalne = "Ljubljana" });

                i3.Prodajalna.Add(new Prodajalna() { imeProdajalne = p.imeProdajalne, naslovProdajalne = "Koper" });

                context.Igre.Add(i1);
                context.Igre.Add(i2);
                context.Igre.Add(i3);
                base.Seed(context);
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: How to make it that it will only write out those one time, as stated at the end of my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with these 2 lines:

```
i2.Prodajalna.Add(new Prodajalna() { imeProdajalne = "Nekaj2", naslovProdajalne = "Koper" });
i3.Prodajalna.Add(new Prodajalna() { imeProdajalne = "Nekaj2", naslovProdajalne = "Koper" });
```

What you really want is to create a single *Prodajalna* and reuse it.  The simplest way to accomplish this is to save the object first, and the re-use it.

```
var p = new Prodajalna() { imeProdajalne = "Nekaj2", naslovProdajalne = "Koper" };
_dbContext.Prodajalna.Add(p);
_dbContext.Save();

i2.Prodajalna.Add(p);
i3.Prodajalna.Add(p);
```

Comment: what is the _dbContext and _datacontext?

Comment: sorry, those are the same thing, I updated my answer.  your _dbContext is your EF data context.  `public class YourNameHere : DbContext`

Comment: My context name is ProdajalnaVsebujeIgroContext, and if I try to write .Prodajalna to it doesn't find it, it only has two functions which is equals and  ReferenceEquals

Comment: Updated my answer, still don't know how to resolve this

Comment: move you SaveChanges() call to just AFTER the .Add() call.